Agent won't learn no matter what I try
I am trying to make an RL model for reinforcement learning, and the environment is fairly simple and a 10x10 grid. During the training phase, it reaches the goal. But when I try to test this, The agent takes one direction and goes straight and hits a wall or obstacle. It won't change direction. And this goes on in a loop. My reward function is based on distance from the current position to the goal and penalties are given for moving away from the goal and hitting anything. The following given is my model class.
class DQNTrainer:
    def __init__(self, states, actions, visualize=True, load_model=False):
        self.states = states
        self.actions = actions
        self.model = self.create_model()
        if load_model:
            self.load_model()
        self.agent = self.create_agent()
        self.env = None
        self.visualize = visualize

    def create_model(self):
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Flatten(input_shape=(1, self.states, self.states)))
        model.add(Dense(128, activation="relu", kernel_regularizer=l1(0.01)))  # Add L1 regularization
        model.add(Dense(128, activation="relu", kernel_regularizer=l1(0.01)))
        model.add(Dense(64, activation="relu", kernel_regularizer=l1(0.01)))
        model.add(Dense(self.actions, activation="linear"))
        return model

    def create_agent(self):
        policy = LinearAnnealedPolicy(EpsGreedyQPolicy(), 
                                  attr='eps', 
                                  value_max=1.0, 
                                  value_min=0.1, 
                                  value_test=0.01, 
                                  nb_steps=10000)
        return DQNAgent(
            model=self.model,
            memory=SequentialMemory(limit=20000, window_length=1),
            policy=policy,
            #policy = EpsGreedyQPolicy(0.1),
            nb_actions=self.actions,
            nb_steps_warmup=500,
            target_model_update=0.005,
            gamma=0.99
        )

    def compile_agent(self):
        self.agent.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.0005), 
                           metrics=['mean_absolute_error'])

    def fit(self, env, nb_steps):
        self.env = env
        self.agent.fit(self.env, nb_steps=nb_steps, visualize=self.visualize, verbose=1)

    def train(self, env, nb_steps):
        self.compile_agent()
        self.fit(env, nb_steps)
        return True

    def save_model(self):
        self.model.save_weights('pathplanner.h5', overwrite=True)

    def load_model(self):
        try:
            self.model.load_weights('pathplanner.h5')
            print("Model Loading Successful")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error loading model: {e}")


How heavily do you penalize for hitting something?
good boy points ->  +1
not good boy points -> -10

maybe it would be simpler if you would create minimal reproducible example so we could copy and run it. You may also try to ask on similar portals DataScience or CrossValidated or Artificial Intelligence

@AshwinPhadke I have tried various rewards but the ones I am currently using are {100:for reaching goal, 1:for moving closer to goal, -10:for moving away, -10: for collision} and another one is {200:for reaching goal, 10/ (1+distance_to_goal): for moving towards goal, -50: for moving away, -50: for hitting obstacles}

@furas I'm sorry, Unfortunately, I can't do that. But the general workflow is like this. The model is given part of a map and is expected to predict the coordinates to reach the goal. The env has standard fn such as step(), reset(), render() etc and also a fn to calculate distance. In step() it receives an action, ie left, right, up, or down as a tuple and first, it checks if the position is valid, if it is the robot pos is set to this value, if it's not then it's considered as collision / out of bound. Then the coordinate is saved to a queue. Then it's checked if the goal is reached ...

also, the goal is being reached but the reward is kinda stable always in the -9.5 region

you didn't show how you train it - maybe this is problem. But I think you should ask experts on DataScience

I'll try to post there too. For training, I take a large map and then a part of the map is only given to the model. The mini-map has 0 for free space, 1 for obstacles, 2 for robot and 3 for goal. The model takes these and tries to predict the points to reach the goal. I'm confused because, during training, it's reaching the goal and predicting the coordinates. But during testing, the agent goes up and down in 1 block.

Do Check this out too. The agent behaves like this when tested and gets stuck. https://imgur.com/a/bWUZuEo

Here's what I would do, I would play with the reward function a bit more and mostly figure out what is an ideal set of points to compute for maximum explore-exploit ratio. Somehow the magnitude of the rewards simply don't match. Plot the rewards from your fit to understand the difference in winning magnitudes and strategies and adjust accordingly.
